# Find tuple within tuple as a dictionary key

Tags: python, function, dictionary, tuples

For a dungeon crawler, I have multiple game levels that can be navigated by using a 2d list as a grid. The dungeons are all unique objects with many attributes, including tuples representing interactive event locations.

```
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = "The Catacombs"
        self.level = 1
        self.throne = (2, 3)
        self.fountain = (3, 3)
        self.teleporter = (4, 3)
        self.pit = (2, 4)
        ....
```

The next part of the code exists as a player class function.
The player's coordinates are stored as a tuple. If the player's coordinates exist as a key in a dictionary, a corresponding function is called..

```
def event_logic(self):
    self.coordinates = (self.x, self.y)
    event_dict = {self.dungeon.throne: self.throne_event,
                  self.dungeon.fountain: self.fountain_event,
                  self.dungeon.teleporter: self.teleporter_event,
                  self.dungeon.pit: self.pit_event

                      }

        if self.coordinates in event_dict.keys():
            event_function = (event_dict[self.coordinates])
            return event_function()
```

The problem is that this only allows me to have one such event per level; I am using one tuple for each key. I want to have a few pits to fall into and a few thrones to sit on or pry gems from. So, after realizing that lists cannot be used as keys, I tried using a tuple of tuples, like, `self.throne = ((2,3), (18,4)....)` to allow me to have multiple events throughout, but that does not work, because the player's coordinates do not exactly match the tuple of tuples.
I need a way to determine if 1 tuple exists within multiple tuples within the dictionary keys to call the corresponding function. If this is not possible, I need an alternative way..

Comment: I assume each item has unique coordinates? No items happen to have the same coordinates?

Comment: I notice that in the dungeon class example, every item has 1 pair of coordinates. But in the last paragraph, you have `self.throne = ...` with multiple pairs of coordinates. Shouldn't the example also show tuples of tuples for each attribute, even for cases where there is only a 1-element outer tuple? For consistency?

Comment: That is correct. No items share the same coordinates. I mentioned that I had tried tuples of tuples, which do not work. Single tuples work fine and allow the program to run..

Comment: In that case: just make your `event_dict` contain a single pair/tuple of coordinates for each throne, fountain or other item. Creating `event_dict` takes a bit more (you need to loop over all coordinate pairs for each item and insert them), but it solves your problem quite logically.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing now, which works fine. But I can only have one self.throne, self.pit.....per level.

Comment: Your `event_dict` is separate from your level/dungeon, so you can add more thrones to it. What I wrote above: per level, create a list of throne coords for each level, then add them one-by-one to the events (each with the same event function).

Comment: So, what I did was add ```self.fountain2```,  and ```self.fountain3``` and so forth.. which works. Is that what you were suggesting? I was hoping for something a little more elegant...but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Using dictionary keys like this defeats the quick access purpose of a dictionary.

You'd be better having a dictionary of all events based on co-ordinates allowing you to easily look up multiple events e.g.:

```
self.locations = {}
self.location[(2, 3)] = self.throne_event
self.location[(2, 6)] = self.teleporter_event
self.location[(3, 5)] = self.teleporter_event


if self.coordinates in self.locations():
    location_event = self.locations.get(self.coordinates)
```

This limits you to one event for location.  To allow multiple, store a list at each co-ordinate:

```
location_events = [
    self.throne_event,
    self.fountain_event
]
self.locations[(2, 3)] = location_events
```

Then to action the player's coordinates:

```
events_at_coordinate = self.locations.get(self.coordinates)
for event in events_at_coordinate:
    # do what you would do with your location event(s)
```

Comment: The problem is a little bit more nuanced. self.throne_event is a player class function, not a dungeon class function.

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference.  You should be able to call the throne_event for a player from anywhere.  e.g. if I am iterating through events that need checking for players, I loop through all instances of players, testing their locations again the locations dict and calling methods on instances as necessary (be they player or dungeon methods.)  In your post you said the issue was with your dictionary lookup.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I can't quite make this work for what I need.. I am an absolute beginner. For instance self.location[(2, 3)] and self.throne_event exist in 2 different modules which gives me problems with scope. I also get errors with non-callable types. I upvoted your answer due to your insight, which I will refer back to when I learn more.

Answer (score 1):

it may be easier to not directly work on individual type of items, but rather store the list of items present at each location.
Example:

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.name = "The Catacombs"
    self.level = 1
    self.pois = [
        {"type": "throne", "positions": [(2, 3), (4,5)]},
        {"type": "pit", "positions": [(2, 4), (4,4)]}
    ]
```

Then you can just loop other these to build a second-hand variable:

```
position_to_items = {}
for item_props in self.pois:
    for position in item_props["positions"]:
        if position in position_to_items:
            position_to_items[position].append(item_props["type"])
        else:
            position_to_items[position] = [item_props["type"]]
```

Then, given a position (tuple), you'll directly get the list of items present in the room.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. This is useful, but I can't quite make it work for what I need.

Comment: Ok, if you need a follow-up support, do no hesitate...